# When to use AtomicReference (Java)? Is it really necessary?

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic

I have used AtomicLong many times but I have never needed to use AtomicReference

It seems that AtomicReference does either (I copied this code from another stackoverflow
question):

```
public synchronized boolean compareAndSet(List<Object> oldValue, List<Object> newValue) { 
    if (this.someList == oldValue) {
        // someList could be changed by another thread after that compare,
        // and before this set
        this.someList = newValue;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or

```
public synchronized boolean compareAndSet(List<Object> oldValue, List<Object> newValue) { 
    if (this.someList == oldValue || this.someList.equals(oldValue)) {
        // someList could be changed by another thread after that compare,
        // and before this set
        this.someList = newValue;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Assume this.someList is marked volatile.

I'm not sure really which one it is because the javadoc and the code for that class are not clear if .equals is used.

Seeing how the above methods are not exactly that hard to write has anyone ever used AtomicReference?

Comment: [They](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22import+java.util.concurrent.atomic.atomicreference%22&) have ever used it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a *reference*, so that's what is compared. The documentation makes it very clear that it's an identity comparison, even using the `==` operation in [its description.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#compareAndSet%28V,%20V%29)

I use `AtomicReference` and other atomic classes very frequently. Profiling shows that they perform better than the equivalent methods using synchronization. For example, a `get()` operation on an `AtomicReference` requires only a fetch from main memory, while a similar operation using `synchronized` must first flush any values cached by threads to main memory and then perform its fetch.

The `AtomicXXX` classes provide access to native support for compare-and-swap (CAS) operations. If the underlying system supports it, CAS will be faster than any scheme cooked up with `synchronized` blocks in pure Java.

Comment: Of course I am a moron. Its java.lang.ref
I was thinking it was something like AtomicObject if there was one.

Comment: How would you comment this benchmark: https://edgblog.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/synchronization-vs-atomicreference-test/ ?

Comment: @WaldemarWosiński Using an `AtomicLong` to maintain the value will be faster than a `long` in a `synchronized` block, which would be a direct apples-to-apples comparison. Object allocation accounts for some of the difference, but this is exacerbated by retries due to failed comparisons in CAS. If you care about speed in concurrent applications, stick to operations that are free from side-effects (like the `long` or `AtomicLong` implementations).